# How to find the RMS value of a sine wave with DC offset and retain the negative sign

Tags: analog, rms, dds, quadrature

I'm trying to build a Quadrature setup where an input signal is mixed with a reference signal that is in-phase and another one out-of-phase by 90deg.

The idea is to extract the real and imaginary amplitudes (magnitude and phase) in a signal produced by an impedance when excited with the reference signal.

However, I'm trying to get around having to sample both of the mixed signals using an ADC and then extract the data - due to sampling rate limitations.

To enable this, I'm trying to use an AC-TrueRMS converter (AD8436BRQZ) that would produce the RMS equivalent DC signal.

However, I want to retain the negative sign, if the signal for example is fully negative (i.e. with a DC offset).

Is converting to RMS not the right approach?

Thanks

[image: Proposed block diagram]

Comment: By definition RMS removes the sign. Can you add a sketch of the waveforms and desired output?

Comment: Haha yeah just about to say that, RMS is designed to be a way to get the magnitude (scalar therefore not negative). Also your method is flawed because you'll lose all phase information by generating an RMS DC signal for comparison, this would erase all hope of getting real vs imaginary info for you signal. If you know the phase of your supply signal (best case scenario if it is generated by the same device measuring the circuit output with its ADC), then you can do all the signal mixing/computations digitally after sampling only the one "circuit response" signal.

Comment: Normally AFAIK your IQ detector mixes the I & Q components down to baseband, so there's no need for a further RMS detector to recover the "DC" signals. A block diagram of your system might make it more clear what you need.

Comment: I've attached the block diagram.

Comment: My primary need is to extract the real and imaginary values, ideally they should just be a DC signal? I dont know if that possible, but surely LCR meters that work at MHz, wont be able to sample multiple times during the cycle of a sine wave?

Comment: What is your desired sampling frequency? The photo of your block diagram is pretty hard to read, by the way.

Comment: Around 400Hz, it is smaller than the nyquist limit for a signal of 5000Hz. I've decided to ditch the RMS-to-DC and instead use an LPF that rejects anything above a few Hz.